# The number of ways in which 10 balls can be selected from 10 identical green balls, 10 identical blue balls and 9 identical red balls are?

Tags: combinatorics

The number of ways in which 10 balls can be selected from 10 identical green balls, 10 identical blue balls and 9 identical red balls are?

I feel the answer should be $c(29,10)$, but apparently, that's wrong, what would be the correct way to solve this?

Comment: Note that Stars and Bars almost works here, since there are enough green and blue and almost enough red.  You just have to exclude the case(s) in which stars and bars calls for more red balls then you have.  Note that your expression would only make sense if all the balls were distinct, but that's not the case here.

Comment: " Stars and Bars" . What's that?

Comment: [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: For reference, $\binom{29}{10}$ would have been the answer had the balls *not* been identical.  If all 29 balls were uniquely colored and/or uniquely labeled, yes we are choosing 10 of the 29 balls.  In the problem statement however it is emphasized that the green balls are all identical, so a selection where we have the "first green ball" vs a selection where we had the "second green ball" but no other differences should be considered to be the same outcome.

Comment: Be warned that if we were to extend the problem to talk about probabilities of certain events occurring, even though the balls may have been stated to be identical the most reasonable interpretation of the meaning of "taking 10 balls at random" lends itself to calculations where we intentionally ignore this and treat the balls all as distinct.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem statement does not state 10 unique ways.  It is like taking 10 pills from a bottle of Vitamin D tables.  The problem statement does not state that these ways are unique!  So if one chooses 3 blue balls or 3 different blue balls, these are separate possibilities.  It is pretty controversial so I am not exposing my hint to a vote.  But I hold that it is that 10+10+9=29.  And therefore the number of possibilities are $\text{number of ways}=29*28*27*26*25*24*23*22*21*20$.  The number itself can be calculated easily with a regular calculator that has enough precision.

Comment: @StephenElliott there are of course problems whose answer are what you came up with, but *traditionally* problems phrased in this way are intended to be interpreted as I have below.  A question with the answer you came up with related to this would have been written more like "*In how many ways can you pull 10 balls in sequence if we had 10 green, 10 blue, and 9 red balls all of which distinct?*"  That is a very different problem.  The explicit inclusion of the word "*identical*" in "*10 identical green balls*" as well as no explicit reference to order are the clues that they're different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the upper limits on each type of ball, with $r$ types of ball available the number of ways taking $n$ balls would be given by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) as

$$\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$$

(*or equivalently, this is the number of ways of placing $n$ balls into $r$ labeled bins.  order irrelevant, balls identical, and no requirements on upper or lower limits on number of balls in each bin in the end*)

Here with $n=10$ and $r=3$, this is exactly the procedure used to count the number of outcomes in this scenario with one minor exception... it would also count the case of having chosen $10$ red balls which is impossible as there are only $9$ red balls available.

Subtracting this one case away corrects the count.

Note that had we been asked to take more balls, there would similarly be more impossible selections which we would need to consider.  Depending on circumstance this may require more lengthy analysis including possibly needing to invoke the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), or perhaps it might in some circumstances be easier to count the number of ways you can pick what is *not* chosen rather than to pick what *is* chosen (*here for instance if we were asked to take 25 balls, we could simply pick the four balls that are left behind and take the rest rather than using a lengthy inclusion-exclusion argument*).